# Neo4j out of order sequence error

Tags: neo4j

Does anyone know why I might receive the following error while Neo4j is running: "Waiting for all transactions to close... out-of-order-sequence"?  This just repeats again and again.

[image]

This seems to occur after heavy writing, but I'm unsure as to what is actually causing it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check your logs?

Comment: Which version of neo4j are you using?

Comment: @MattiasPersson Using version 2.2.2.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you shut down in the middle of this heavy writing, or after? Also can you find any exception in messages.log or similar?